# Class $C^1$ with "open" domain?

Tags: general-topology

In my book, a function is of class $C^1$ if it's defined on an open domain and ... (and then the rest follows in regards to the derivatives), but what if it's defined on a closed domain? So then it can't be a $C^1$ function?

What if the domain is all real numbers? Is this a closed domain or open?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is both, closed and open. In principle, nothing forbids defining $C^1$ functions on closed (or neither closed nor open) domains, one just needs that every point is a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

For any topology on a set $X$, $\emptyset$ and $X$ are both open and closed. Or, in the topology jargon, $\emptyset$ and $X$ are always "[clopen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set)".

As for why an open domain is used, it is because it makes the domain an open submanifold of the differentiable manifold that you are working with. In less snazzy terms, this just means that we have a clean definition of what we mean by a continuously differentiable function in more general and abstract settings.